# Get specific attribute from kubectl describe node

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I am trying to get the maximum capacity of pod per node. I am running `kubectl describe node nodename` and trying to grep the pods limit in capacity section. Any help would be appreciated. The output is like this.

```
Capacity:
  attachable-volumes-azure-disk:  8
  cpu:                            4
  ephemeral-storage:              129900528Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:                  0
  hugepages-2Mi:                  0
  memory:                         16393308Ki
  pods:                           110
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use just native ooptions of kubectl command

`kubectl get nodes <nodename> -o jsonpath='{.status.capacity.pods}{"\n"}'`

If you dont need trailing newline character after the output:

`kubectl get nodes <nodename> -o jsonpath='{.status.capacity.pods}'`

Answer (score 0):

try the below command

```
kubectl describe no node01 | sed -n '/Capacity/,/pods/p' | grep -i pods | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I want to get only the value

Comment: updated the command. check now